# Rebuild query which looking for specific string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have products numbers which looks like below:

One example product (contain couple articles)

```
14.12312.1
14.12312.2
14.12312.3
14.12312.4
14.12312.5
```

Other example product (contain couple articles)

```
003.23.1
003.23.66
003.23.44
003.23.77
003.23.5
```

Important thing here is dots are separators:

```
<producentNumber>.<specialnumber>.<articlevariation>
```

Now i got query which could take first part of specific product for instance i can pass: `003.23.` (with last dot) and then it gives me all starts with it so:

```
003.23.1
003.23.66
003.23.44
003.23.77
003.23.5
```

This is the query which is doing that:

```
SELECT ID, Nummer FROM [Cenea].[dbo].[T_Artikel] 
                  WHERE
                  SUBSTRING(Nummer, 0, LEN(Nummer) + 2 -  CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(Nummer)))  IN 
                  (
                                                                                         '003.23.'
                  )
```

However now is the change that within last part of the articles number could appears dots and not only the numbers so it means i can have like this:

```
 003.23.1
 003.23.66..dwqd
 003.23.4422.323.3
 003.23.77....f
 003.23.5
```

So when i pass `003.23.` i will get not all but just 003.23.1 in this case. The logic stays as it was first two dots are holding the base but after the second there could be anything. Question is how to rebuild my sql query to adapt the change to get alkl articles?

Hope everything is clear and please provide working code as i have to make change on production today.

Comment: no solution yet means it is not clear.Simply first say when you pass "003.23." then what output you should get.?and also what is your input table.According to me LIKE '003.23.%',it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) to get all rows where `Number` starts with `<some value>`:

```
SELECT ID, Nummer FROM [Cenea].[dbo].[T_Artikel] 
WHERE Number LIKE '003.23%'
```